# Characterization of Linear Transformations between Tensor Products

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I am seeking to show that $$\mathcal{L}(V\otimes X,W\otimes Y) \cong \mathcal{L}(V,W)\otimes \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$$ where $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is the space of linear transformations from $V$ into $W$.

To show that there is an injective linear transformation from the right to left, it isn't hard to show that the assignment $(S,T)\mapsto S\otimes T$ for linear transformations $S:V\rightarrow W$ and $T:X\rightarrow Y$ defines a multilinear map from $\mathcal{L}(V,W)\times \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ to $\mathcal{L}(V\otimes X,W\otimes Y)$, so that the universal property of the Tensor Product can be used.

Using the Schroeder-Bernstein Property of linear transformations (i.e. that if there are injective linear transformations $S:V\rightarrow W$ and $T:W\rightarrow V$, then there is an isomorphism between $V$ and $W$), it suffices to show that there is an injection from $\mathcal{L}(V\otimes X,W\otimes Y)$ into $\mathcal{L}(V,W)\otimes \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$.  In order to show this, I am trying to show that given a linear transformation $U: V\otimes X\rightarrow W\otimes Y$, there are unique linear transformations $S:V\rightarrow W$ and $T:X\rightarrow Y$, so that $U=S\otimes T$.

In my attempt to prove this, I want to show that for basis vectors $v_i\in V$ and $x_i\in X$, $U(v_i\otimes x_i)=w_i\otimes y_i$.  Defining then $S(v_i)=w_i$ and $T(x_i)=y_i$, this should give me the unique linear transformations I want.

However, I can neither know nor know how to prove whether it is necessarily that $U(v_i\otimes x_i)=w_i\otimes y_i$ for an arbitrary linear transformation.  i.e. do pure tensors always map to pure tensors, or more specifically do pure basis tensors map to pure tensors?

If otherwise, how would I be able to form the above injection?

Comment: If you're working with finite-dimensional spaces, then the standard argument for surjectivity of the canonical (right-to-left) map is using injectivity and the rank-nullity theorem. If you're working with infinite-dimensional spaces, then from what I recall, the canonical injection is not generally surjective.

Comment: Would it work to show that both sides are isomorphic to the space of 4-multilinear forms on $V \times W \times X \times Y$?

Comment: Simple tensors do not need to map to simple tensors.  If $\{v_i\}$ and $\{x_i\}$ are bases for $V$ and $X$, then $\{v_i \otimes x_j\}$ is a basis for $V \otimes X$ and you can specify a linear map $V \otimes X \to W \otimes Y$ by choosing **any** images for those basis vectors, simple or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert, but wouldn't the following work?

Assume that $V,W,X,Y$ are all finite dimensional vector spaces and $\dim V = v$, $\dim W = w$, $\dim X = x$ and $\dim Y = y$. Then $V \cong \mathbb{K}^v$, $W \cong \mathbb{K}^w$, 
$X\cong \mathbb{K}^x$ and $Y \cong \mathbb{K}^y$.

We know that $\mathbb{K}^p \otimes \mathbb{K}^q \cong \mathbb{K}^{pq}$. Hence, we need to prove that:
$$L(\mathbb{K}^{vx},\mathbb{K}^{wy}) \cong L(\mathbb{K}^v,\mathbb{K}^w) \otimes L(\mathbb{K}^x,\mathbb{K}^y)$$

We know that $L(\mathbb{K}^{vx},\mathbb{K}^{wy}) \cong \mathbb{K}^{vxwy}$, $L(\mathbb{K}^v,\mathbb{K}^w) \cong \mathbb{K}^{vw}$ and $L(\mathbb{K}^x,\mathbb{K}^y) \cong \mathbb{K}^{xy}$. Moreover:
$$L(\mathbb{K}^v,\mathbb{K}^w) \otimes L(\mathbb{K}^x,\mathbb{K}^y) \cong \mathbb{K}^{vw} \otimes \mathbb{K}^{xy} \cong \mathbb{K}^{vwxy}$$
Clearly, $\mathbb{K}^{vxwy} \cong \mathbb{K}^{vwxy}$.

Comment: That certainly answers the question for the finite-dimensional case.  I'm under the impression that this holds for infinite-dimensional vector spaces as well, in which case the above couldn't be used.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not for the infinite case, no. Sorry.